# Distance calculation between points on similar point clouds

Tags: calculated-columns, point-clouds, measurement

Annotate points 1 and 2 on a point cloud model A, find points 1' and 2' (or their closest points) on another identical point cloud B, and calculate the distance between points 1' and 2' on point cloud B.

Tried, but the plan was unpassed

1. Make a linear analytical expression and calculate the intersection point between the line and the plane
2. Calculate the vector angle between two points to verify whether the points are accurate.  If they are accurate, calculate the vector length
   The plan being tried:
3. Project the 3D point cloud of the object onto a 2D plane and calculate the length between two points on the plane